# How to add, delete, update, read only one entry in a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json

**Questions.**
1. How to add, delete, update, read only one entry in a JSON file?
2. Is it possible to programmatically add, delete an entry from the file "SettingJson.json"?

**Description.**
I suggest using a JSON file to store application settings.
How to read and write the whole file, I figured it out.

If I understand correctly, then:
**Delete:**
1. Remove the property from the "Settings.cs" class;
2. Delete the property from the file "SettingJson.json";

**Add:**
1. Add a property from the "Settings.cs" class;
2. Add a property from the file "SettingJson.json";

**Update:**
???

**Read:**
???

**Settings.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public string NameSetting1 { get; set; }
        public string NameSetting2 { get; set; }                
        public string NameSetting3 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
// 
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Settings[] settings = new Settings[] { };
            settings = FillArrayAll();

            SaveDataArray(settings);
        }



        static Settings[] FillArrayAll()
        {
            Settings[] settings = new Settings[]
            {
                new Settings()
                {
                    NameSetting1 = "ValueSetting_1",
                    NameSetting2 = "ValueSetting_2",
                    NameSetting3 = "ValueSetting_3"
                }
            };
            return settings;
        }


        static Settings[] FillArrayOneItem()
        {
            Settings[] settings = new Settings[]
            {
                new Settings()
                {                    
                    NameSetting2 = "ValueSetting_2",                    
                }
            };
            return settings;
        }


        static void SaveDataArray(Settings[] settings)
        {
            string path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\SettingsFolder\\SettingJson.json";

            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
                writer.Write(output);
            }
        }

        public Settings[] ReadData()
        {
            string path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\SettingsFolder\\SettingJson.json";            

            using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                var fileText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings[]> (fileText);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

---

### Update-1

*Based on materials from the answer `Pavel Anikhouski - 2020-02-28 16: 16`*

How to make separate methods?

**The "Write" method.**
*Gets:*

- key-value (one key or a collection of keys);
- path to the file `SettingJson.json`.

*Performs:*
 - writes data to `SettingJson.json`.

**The Read Method.**
*Gets:*
  - key (one key or collection of keys);
  - path to the file `SettingJson.json`.

*Performs:*
   - reads data from `SettingJson.json`.

*Returns:*
  - key value (values or a collection of values).

Comment: If you want to modify entries use a `List<T>`, not an array

Comment: You can use `Json.Linq` for that

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski **1.** Or `BindingList<T>`? **2.**What is the logic of my actions?
Example:
  2.1. extract all `JSON`;
  2.2. place the result in `List <T>`;
  2.3. find the record by the desired key;
  2.4. update;
  2.5. Save `List <T>` in `JSON`;

Comment: [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) implements `IDictionary` and `ICollection`, there is no need to use a `List`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski What is `NameSetting1` in my case?
Key or field?

Comment: @koverflow This is a key, definitely. I'll add an answer with some code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Json.Linq](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm) for manipulation with json, e.g. create [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) from `Settings` using [`FromObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/FromObject.htm) method and manipulate with it

```cs
var settings = FillArrayAll();
//create JObject from settings
var created = JObject.FromObject(new { settings });
 //convert to json
var json = created.ToString();
//write json to a file
//…
//read it back
var updated = JObject.Parse(json);
//get value by key
var key = updated["settings"]?.FirstOrDefault()?["NameSetting1"];
//add new empty Settings to an array
(updated["settings"] as JArray)?.Add(JObject.FromObject(new Settings()));
//convert the updated object back to json
var resultJson = updated.ToString();
```

The comments near code should be pretty explanatory.

You can also find some details at [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm), [Parsing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm) and [Creating JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: @koverflow Does it answer your question, do you need more information or details?

Comment: See `Update-1`
I can’t understand what’s going on.
Could you do by separate methods.

Comment: **2.** When interacting with "* .json" files, if I perform data `read` and `write` operations, does the program perform these actions for the entire contents of the file?
In other words, I can’t access a specific key in the file and do `read` and `write`?

Comment: @koverflow Sorry, but this site isn't a free code writing service, only you can answer what's going on in your code. I've already added code sample and links to article, which allows you to solve your problem, please have a look at it. It's up to you how to read and write the data to file, partial read and update a file with json content does't make a lot of sense, you can broke the entire structure and can't read it again